# What is .$uibModal in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I got this code

```
$uibModal.open({
templateurl:'',
controller:'',
backdrop:'',
size:''
resolve: ''
```

Can someone explain me its usage and what are its parameters usage?

Comment: you'd better have a look at [documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`$uibModal` is a service to create modal windows. It has an `open` method, that will return a modal instance.

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                     templateUrl: 'view/sample.html',
                     controller: 'testController',// a controller for modal instance
                     controllerUrl: 'controller/test-controller', // can specify controller url path
                     controllerAs: 'ctrl', //  controller as syntax
                     windowClass: 'clsPopup', //  can specify the CSS class
                     keyboard: false, // ESC key close enable/disable
                     resolve: {
                         actualData: function () {
                             return self.sampleData;
                         }
                     } // data passed to the controller
                 }).result.then(function (data) {
                     //do logic
                 }, function () {
                     // action on popup dismissal.
                 });
```

Answer (score 13):

It is a service for opening modals in AngularJs. It is a part of "**UI Bootstrap - AngularJS directives specific to Bootstrap**" project.

**Documentation** is here:

- https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal/docs

**Project details** is here:

- https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap

Happy reading :).